# Почему не срабатывает ввод в строки с клавиатуры? C++

Tags: c++, ввод, поток-ввода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct member
{
    string name;
    double distance = -1;
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<member> a(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //cin.clear()
        for (size_t z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        {
            string inp;
            cin >> inp;
            a[i].name += " " + inp; 
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            double input;
            cin >> input;
            if (input > a[i].distance)
                a[i].distance = input;
        }
    }
}
```

Примеры моих входных данных (3 слова, потом 6 чисел или 'x'):

```
8
GER Christian Reif 8.18 x 8.22 8.12 8.12 7.96
RSA Godfrey Mokoena 8.00 7.91 7.87 7.93 8.01 8.10
BRA Mauro Silva x x 8.09 8.05 8.23 8.24
MEX Luis Rivera 7.92 8.16 8.17 8.03 8.27 x
ESP Eusebio Caceres 8.09 8.25 8.17 x 8.26 8.20
RUS Aleksandr Menkov 8.14 7.96 8.52 8.43 8.56 x
JAM Damar Forbes 8.02 7.89 x x 8.00 x
NED Ignisious Gaisah 8.09 8.15 8.17 8.29 x 8.16
```

Однако если дать на вход моей программе эти данные, то она считает только

```
8
GER Christian Reif 8.18 x 8.22 8.12 8.12 7.96
```

И я нашел способ исправить это - `cin.clear()` (я его закомментировал). Но вопрос. В чем причина данной проблемы? Почему `cin.clear()` ее исправляет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы в `double` пытаетесь ввести символ `'x'` из-за чего `cin` переходит в состояние `fail` (константа `failbit`) и не может больше читать данные, `cin.clear()` восстанавливает состояние потока из `fail` в `good` (константа `goodbit`) после чего `cin` снова может считывать данные.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear

Answer (score 2):

Правильный ввод - построчный с помощью `std::getline()`, а потом парсинг полученных строк по словам опять таки строками. Начиная с 3 слова делать `std::stod` с проверкой на исключение. Тогда никаких проблем из-за ввода не будет.